# Display the enum value that is passed to c++ class constructor

Tags: c++, class, enums

I have written a short test code for passing enum value to class constructor. It works well with the compiler. However, the output is weird. The Display() does not show the enum value. It only shows "The strategy of the current agent is ". What's wrong with this code? Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Agent
{
public:
    enum Strat {BuyandHold, Momentum, TA};
    Agent(Strat strategy=BuyandHold);
    ~Agent();
    void Display();
private:
    Strat strategy;
};

Agent::Agent(Strat strategy)
{
    strategy = strategy;
}

Agent::~Agent()
{
    cout << "Bye!" << endl;
}

void Agent::Display()
{
    cout << "The strategy of the current agent is ";
    switch(strategy){
    case BuyandHold : cout << "BuyandHold." << endl; break;
    case Momentum : cout << "Momentum." << endl; break;
    case TA : cout << "TA." << endl; break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Agent a(Agent::TA);
    a.Display();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to distinguish local parameter name declarations from class members. Just provide a different name for your initialization parameter:

```
Agent::Agent(Strat strategy_)
: strategy(strategy_) {}
```

I prefer the `_` postfix to either mark class member variables, or parameter names, since either way is standard compliant (using such as `_` prefix won't be, and anything else like e.g. `m_` prefix for class member variables is clumsy IMHO).

**Also note:**
I've been using member initializer list to assign the class member variable, that's the right choice for most of the use cases.